# Has groovy base install been shrinked from fuerte?

Tags: catkin, rosdep, stacks, build, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed groovy on a pandaboard following [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source)

Now I'm trying building the hokuyo node and I'm missing a LOT of dependencies:

- sensor_msgs
- geometry_msgs
- diagnostic_msgs
- diagnostic_updater
- self_test
- dynamic_reconfigure

And possibly more.
Now I have two problems with this:

1. Why do I have do manually download so many packages there were previously part of the base install?
2. Is there a way to automate package downloading and building? Isn't rosdep supposed to be the solution to this? why doesn't `$ rosmake <package_name> --rosdep-install` work anymore? (no such option)

I may also point out that groovy builds with catkin, why instructions for the hokuyo for example still point to rosmake so I'm doing a mix here, and I hope in the end it will work.

Edit: http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Releases doesn't exist. So I'm manually perusing the svn trying to find the package source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52904/has-groovy-base-install-been-shrinked-from-fuerte?/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5459/zen/) on 2013-07-19**:
Hi Claudio, does dynamic_reconfigure solved the hokuyo_node install issues? I have same issue for install hokuyo_node, but after i install dynamic_reconfigure, seems nothing change. i have no idea how it's work. can you point out what should i do on next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The page you linked to tells you that there are more variants you can use with the wstool command, so that the pacakages you miss would be included (e.g. 'robot'). I have not tried this though, so maybe there are problems with that.

Find latest dynamic_reconfigure on github now, as many other ros packages:
https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure

The hokuyo_node package seems to still use rosbuild/rosmake, so to install this from source, you will need a rosbuild workspace in addition to the catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-25**:
Most of the mentioned packages are available in the Mobile variant. Thanks KruseT.